# .NET 6 to .NET 8 troubleshooting

Tags: datagrid, blazor, .net-6.0, .net-8.0, radzen

I'm working on a Blazor project with .NET 6 framework and it works fine. I'm using Radzen too.

Since I go to .NET 8, I get a problem with grouping on a Radzen Grid.
The grouping never ends and i get many errors messages in the Output window like this :

[image]

Do someone meet this king of trouble by updating to .NET 8 ?

I made a repair of Visual Studio 2022 but nothing changes.

I compare with Radzen tutorial and I see more dll in the debug folder but I don't know since I don't have those in my folder.